# How to add a new Android emulator in ADT behind proxy?

Tags: android

I need an emulator with API level 16. The current version the latest ADT is level 17. Being behind a proxy, I am unable to access the Android repository to add new API versions.

From other workarounds I found on SO, I was able to install the SDK for level 16 - but that's missing the emulator (that is, the tools folder). I downloaded the tools folder for r16.. it is still not displaying the other emulators (apart from the ones I already got with ADT).

Is there any other mechanism I can try offline ?

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you want to install new SDK.

You can actually set Proxy configuration in SDK Manager. Open Android SDK Manager then Tools > Options there you can set proxy server url and port. Default user will be used by default otherwise proxy authentication popup should prompt for input.